# How to keep OpenSessionInView only use stateless session by default on Spring.NET/NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, spring.net, open-session-in-view

our project only query data over a legacy database, can we use a stateless session by default when spring framework auto injected session by OSIV situation?

I mean the base class NHibernateRepository's method GetCurrentSession can retrieve a stateless session object.

Does it work that I change _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession() to _sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession() ?

```
public abstract class NHibernateRepository
{
    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    public ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        protected get { return _sessionFactory; }
        set { _sessionFactory = value; }
    }

    protected ISession CurrentSession
    {
        get { return _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession(); }
    }
......
```

But my Spring configurations will left as the regular setting:

```
<!-- Session Factory Configuration -->
<object id="SessionFactory" type="MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.NHibernateLocalSessionFactoryObject, MyProject.Infrastructure">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="MyDbProvider"/>
    <property name="MappingAssemblies">
        <list>
            <value>MyProject.DataAccess.NHibernateMappingLocal</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Anything should I do for my case? thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried it out? What were your findings?